# Why is KeyManagerUtils.loadStore private?

Tags: apache-commons-net

I am working on a project and I have implemented something like this...

```
    public static KeyStore getInstance(String storeType, Resource location, String password) throws IOException,
        KeyStoreException,
        CertificateException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance((storeType != null ? storeType : DEFAULT_STORE_TYPE));
        try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(location.getFile())) {
            keyStore.load(fileInputStream, password.toCharArray());
        }
        return keyStore;
    }
```

I noticed that common-net has something [similar in loadStore](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/net/util/KeyManagerUtils.html) but it is private. Why is that? Is it something about the way the manager is constructed or something?